# How to set custom font to PagerAdapter title?

Tags: android, android-tabs, custom-font, android-pageradapter

I have sliding tabs layout which displays `PagerAdapter` with the following code:

```
public class TabsPagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {
String[] tabs;
Activity activity;

public TabsPagerAdapter(Activity activity){
    this.activity=activity;
    tabs = new String[]{"Tab 1", "Tab 2", "Tab 3"};
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return tabs.length;
}

@Override
public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object o) {
    return o == view;
}

@Override
public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
    return tabs[position];
}

@Override
public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
    // Inflate a new layout from our resources
    View view=null;
    view = activity.getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.pager_item,container, false);
    container.addView(view);

    return view;
}

@Override
public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
    container.removeView((View) object);
}
```

[image: This is how the tabs look]

Method 'getPageTitle()' returns the title for the tab. Now client's requirement is to apply the custom font to the titles of the tabs i.e. "Tab 1", "Tab 2", etc.

Tutorials found online for setting custom fonts are not applicable here as I don't have my own TextView so can not apply custom typefaces to it. How can I change the font of the tab title?

**EDIT**:
I guess I will have to make changes to the support.v4 code found [here](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_support/tree/master/v4/java/android/support/v4).
But I don't see any `TextView` in `view/PagerAdapter` class. I see TextViews in `view/PagerTitleStrip` class. But it is not used from within `PagerAdapter`.

Comment: I think you should inflate your custom view in which your textview will be so you can apply custom font to it.

Comment: If you can use custom library, you could use `astuetz.PagerSlidingTabStrip`, implement `extends FragmentPagerAdapter implements PagerSlidingTabStrip.CustomTabProvider` and pass own xml layout for tab

Comment: Thank you @PiyushGupta. But how will I inflate custom view and set it as the title. When we inflate the views, we set it to the pager and not to the title.

Comment: Thank you @poss. But the code is like 2 years old and this will be a major change to move to a third party library. Also the library you mentioned has many issues reported in github which my client will not accept.